Problem with simulate $X$ with $X|Y = y \sim Exp(y)$ and $Y \sim Exp(1.5)$
II'm trying to simulate $X$ with $X|Y = y \sim Exp(y)$ and $Y \sim Exp(1.5)$, I found that
$$
f_X(x) = \frac{1.5}{(1.5 +x)^2 } , x > 0
$$
When I do the simulation, it does not give me good simulations and it does not seem to fit the curve. Anyone who can help me or tell me what's happening? My code is the following
y = rexp(10^6,1.5)
x = rexp(10^6,y)
hist(x, freq = F)

and I get


It looks like you sometimes genereate extreme outliers, your x-axis goes to 1.2*10^7. Try limiting your x-axis view to much smaller values.

You need much smaller bin widths.  The standard approaches (Sturges, Freedman/Diaconis, etc.) generally work fine but those don't work well for some distributions.  Consider hist(x,breaks=c(0:ceiling(max(x))),xlim=c(0,150), freq=F, las=1) which (as @NikolajPedersen suggests) limits the x-axis and covers about 99% of the distribution.  The other approach (depending on the subject matter objectives) is taking the logs of $x$.
`

The right tail is extremely heavy.  As sample size gets large you'll see more and more extreme values in your sample. Try plotting values below the 99th %ile, say (compare with a correspondlingly truncated version of the density).

You also might consider an "adaptive" approach where each bin contains approximately the same number of observations (and still follow the advice to limit the range of the values of x to display.  The R package ‘Ckmeans.1d.dp contains the function ahist to do exactly that.

You need much smaller bin widths. The standard approaches (Sturges, Freedman/Diaconis, etc.) generally work fine but those don't work well for some distributions. Consider
hist(x,breaks=c(0:ceiling(max(x))),xlim=c(0,150), freq=F, las=1)


which limits the x-axis and covers about 99% of the distribution (as @NikolajPedersen and @Glen_b suggest). The other approach (depending on the subject matter objectives) is taking the logs of x.
.
